# Find unique months and years from date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.1

Trying to find the unique months and years from a date field in a table (not created_at or updated_at) and use those values to populate two select boxes from which the user can choose which years and/or months they want to report on. Essentially, I only want to present the user with the years and months for which there are records. I'm using Postgresql as my db.

I'm currently getting the values using this code in my controller:

```
@list_of_years = @subset.pluck(:usg_date).map{|y| y.year}.uniq.sort
@list_of_months = @subset.pluck(:usg_date).map{|m| m.month}.uniq.sort
```

This works to the extent it gives me the values, but not in the format I want and I can't figure out how to use them to populate the select boxes. For example for month, I want to display Jan, Feb, Mar rather than 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> `Model.select("created_at").map{ |i| i.created_at.year }.uniq`

To get Name of month use you have to use `Date::MONTHNAMES`(First You may need to `require 'date'`)
Eg:

```
LeaveSystem.select("created_at").map{ |i|  Date::MONTHNAMES[i.created_at.month] }.uniq
```

RESULT:  `["December", "February", "March"]`

Comment: That got me months and years, with a few modifications    `@list_of_years = Usage.select(:usg_date).map{ |i| i.usg_date.year }.uniq and  @list_of_months = Usage.select(:usg_date).map{ |i| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[i.usg_date.month] }.uniq`  However, the months are not sorting properly (by calendar order). If I add sort, they sort alphabetically.